# Either there exists an extended real number $A$ such that $X_n \to A$ almost surely or the sequence $X_n$ diverge almost surely.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of independent random variables on a probability space.

Then for the sequence $(X_n)$ either there exists an extended real number $A$ such that $X_n \to A$ a.s. or the sequence $X_n$ diverge almost surely.

Need some hints for the problem.

Comment: Consider what the alternative is. What does it mean if neither of those two statements are true?

Comment: (In other words, if it doesn't approach any extended real $A$ a.s., and doesn't diverge a.s.)

Comment: First show that the events $\{X_n \text{ diverges}\}$ and $\{X_n \to A\}$ are tail events. Then use Kolmogorov's 0-1 law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{\liminf X_n =\limsup X_n\}$ has probability 0 or 1 by Kolmogorv's 0-1 law. If the probability is 0 then $\{X_n\}$ oscillates with probability 1. If it is 1 then  $\liminf X_n =\limsup X_n$ with probability 1 so the sequence converges to a finite limit or to $\infty$ or to $-\infty$ with probability 1.